# Machine learning roadmap not for beginners

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, reinforcement-learning, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning

To introduce myself:
I know what is RL, know some RL algorithms such as PPO, A2C. Know about offline RL, online RL. I have read many papers about RL. Such as MuZero, AplhaZero, Decision Transformer and etc. I also know much about supervised learning. Know many architectures from MPL to modern Transformers. I can solve many tasks. I have read many papers about supervised learning. Such as DETR, VIT, T5, BERT, GPT-3 and many others. I know some things from unsupervised learning. I have read some papers such as DINO, UP-DETR, SIMCLR, and etc. Yesterday i knew about SwAV. I gonna read paper. And learn more about clustering in unsupervised learning. To create Neural Nets i use pytorch.

I'm student at university. I want to be professional AI researcher. And want to work at FAIR.
**Question:**
What should i learn next? Which skills i have to have to be AI researcher?
Please give full roadmap from my current level to level of researcher.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a professional researcher at a top 3 universities in the USA, I will give you my perspective. Please note that everyone's path is different so listen to lots of opinions. The best hints and advises will be part of those opinions so you will get an idea of a possible path. Also, note that I won't assume that you are a prodigy student that you might drop out from college and companies such as FAIR, Google etc will take you under their wings and train you as a researcher. My advice will be mainly focused on what on average you need to increase your chances of success.

First of all, becoming a professional researcher and working at FAIR are 2 different things (that of course can be achieved at the same or at different times). Now, to become a professional researcher you will need professional training = a PhD programme. The PhD years are the years that you will be trained in order to carry out original research. So pursuing a PhD should be your number 1 goal mid-term (after graduating).

Bare in mind that as a Research Scientist in FAIR you will be expected to define your own research path which should align with the objectives of the larger group of researchers that you will belong. This means that you need to ask the right questions. Questions that are interesting and potentially lead to interesting and impactful work. And of course this implies that you know very well the literature of the subject of your research. Also, usually Research Scientists at FAIR, Google etc have already some good impactful research highlights from their PhD/Postdoc and the company is be interested in incorporating these research directions to their research directions. In other words they have something of value to "sell" and not just good skills.

This leads to my next point: specialization. If your goal is to work as a Research Scientist at FAIR (and for example not Google) you need to have specific reasons on why FAIR. Do you like something specific about their research? If you want to become an RL expert for example this might not necessarily lead you to FAIR as they are not as heavily invested in RL compared to e.g. Google. These are things you need to think about.

Having a bit of experience here and there in ML won't lead you anywhere if you don't start focusing on what you want to do in order to achieve your goals. We are talking about a marathon not a sprint so you need to think about long term goals (a plan for the next 10yrs).

Knowing about architectures and have zero ML foundation won't lead you far in the field. As you gain experience start understanding group/family of methods/techniques that do X. For example you might know about PPO, A2C but you might not know what are the differences between Policy Gradient Methods and value methods. These are things that you need to think about for the more focused path that you will take. Successful researchers know very well their field and can come up with successful next steps that push the boundary of their field. You need to build a more general understanding than just knowing about architectures. This leads to my final point: Math.

Being good in Math and Stats is extremely valuable as a researcher in ML. Yes, select the tough path and become good in the math of your field. Don't listen to people telling you that you don't need math.

Few other things: get involved in research groups early to find out what you like. If needed attend a master of research or a master of science especially if you need more courses. Email people to get advice and ask questions again and again! Try to publish early and then apply for a PhD. Choose a good supervisor that will be also a mentor (VERY important as some people are supervising without mentoring). You might end up at a very competitive lab but supervisor might be so busy that you will get nothing from him/her. Think also what YOU get from a project/collaboration/apprenticeship etc. Always keep your math and coding skills sharp. And lastly focus (again), narrow down the research fields that intrigue you.

I tried to cover as much as I could. Good luck with everything and remember exercise patience and persistence!

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful.